# Microsoft.Office.Word.Interop 2nd Document keeps opening as read-only

Tags: c#

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordIterator
{
    class LoadDocument
    {
        public static Document Default()
        {
            try
            {
                return AnyDoc(Filepath.Full());
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Error loading default document.");
            }
        }
        public static Document AnyDoc(string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                object fileName = filepath;

                Application wordApp = new Application { Visible = true };

                Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);

                aDoc.Activate();

                return (aDoc);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Error loading document " + filepath + "!");
            }
        }
    }
}

//Main class

namespace WordIterator
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
         Document doc = LoadDocument.Default();
         doc.SaveAs2(Filepath.Full().Replace(".docx", "_2.docx"));
         Document doc2 = 
         LoadDocument.AnyDoc(@"C:\Users\netha\Documents\FSharpTest\FTEST\ftestdoc3_2.docx");
```

What i'm trying to do: 
Open a word document(do some stuff with it) 
Save it as _2.docx
Then open _2.docx(do some stuff with it)
However the second document keeps opening as read-only, I have it set as read-only false and I've even restarted my computer to make sure it shouldn't be read-only. 
Does anyone know why this is opening as Read-Only?
Thank you for any assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is opening as read-only as you do SaveAs "_2.docx" and then you are trying to open the save document again. I would recommend you to close the active tab and then open the document.

You could use the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;

namespace WordIterator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Test.docx");
            Document doc = null;
            Application wordApp1 =new Application();
            Application wordApp2 = new Application();
            string FilePath2 = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Test_2.docx");
            try
            {
                object fileName = FilePath;
                object fileName2 = FilePath2;
                wordApp1 = new Application { Visible = true };
                doc = wordApp1.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
                doc.SaveAs2(FilePath.Replace(".docx", "_2.docx"));
                doc.Close();
                Document doc2 = wordApp1.Documents.Open(ref fileName2, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot! I worked out that it was mainly the doc.Close() that i needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help Nethalin!